# How to display selected gallery image in imageview in android

Tags: android

I have image view and gallery in the activity.I am getting the image `url` from `WebService`.When user select image in gallery.I have to show correspondace image in `ImageView`  can anybody tell how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){   
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
           Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this,""+position + " Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           imageview.setImageDrawable(bitmap_which_is_displayed);//may be from any array or list
           //or
           imageview.setImageBitmap(drawable_which_is_displayed);//may be from any array or list
       } 
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

To let the user select a image from gallery you can use ::

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setType("image/*");  
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Picture"), requestCode);
```

once the user selects an Image you can get the URI of the image from onActivityResult(Intent intent) method using `uri = intent.getData()`, and set this URI to your image view. do `imageView.setImageURI(uri)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `onItemClick` event for `Gallery` and pass the id of selected picture to another `ImageView` or `ImageSwitcher`. In API demo there's a sample

[ImageSwitcher1](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ImageSwitcher1.html)

and you can check another tutorial [here](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/05/image-switcher-view-android-developer.html)