# ImageView not showing image selected from gallery

Tags: java

So I have a button that loads the gallery, and selects an image using this code...

```
public void getGalleryImage(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        galleryImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }


}
```

But when it goes back to the original activity, the ImageView still doesn't show anything. It doesn't give me any errors, or anything like that. Here the XML for the ImageView...

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/galleryImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

How can I get it to show?

Comment: I think [this link][1] will help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860562/how-to-display-selected-gallery-image-in-imageview-in-android

Comment: check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879992/get-bitmap-from-an-uri-android

All the best

Answer (score 3):

I ended up figuring something out. I just did...

```
 if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        galleryImage.setImageURI(selectedImage);

    }
```

This worked for what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        galleryImage.setImageBitmap(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri));
    }
}
```

Comment: This also works. I ended changing my code to something like this, except I have a try catch around it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    ImageView image;
    Button pick;

    int TAG_IMAGE = 100;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        pick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        pick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("*/*");


                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Image "),TAG_IMAGE);

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == TAG_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK )
        {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();


            try
            {

                String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath,null,null,null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);

                String images = cursor.getString(columnIndex);



                image.setImageURI(selectedImage);


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }



}
```